# Lilith Lady of Lament special summoned by Tour Guide from the Underworld

Tags: yu-gi-oh

By using [Tour Guide from the Underworld](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Tour_Guide_From_the_Underworld), special summoned [Lilith Lady of Lament](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Lilith,_Lady_of_Lament).

**Q:** Can Lilith's effect of tributing monster still be activated? As, tributing 1 dark monster (as a cost), but not have the ability to take 3 traps from the deck.

[Tour Guide from the Underworld](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Tour_Guide_From_the_Underworld):

> When this card is Normal Summoned: You can Special Summon 1 Level 3
>   Fiend monster from your hand or Deck, but it has its effects negated,
>   also it cannot be used as a Synchro Material.

[Lilith Lady of Lament](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Lilith,_Lady_of_Lament):

> If this card is Normal Summoned, its original ATK becomes 1000. (Quick
>   Effect): You can Tribute 1 DARK monster; reveal 3 Normal Traps from
>   your Deck, your opponent randomly chooses 1 for you to Set on your
>   field, and you shuffle the rest back into your Deck. You can only use
>   this effect of "Lilith, Lady of Lament" once per turn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, Lillith's Effect Can Still Be Activated.

Tour Guide From the Underworld's effect states that the effects of the Special Summoned Monster are negated - not that they may not be activated. The distinction is important, because **simply negating the effects of a card does not disallow attempts to activate those effects.**

Applying the concept in the opposite direction, consider [Majesty's Fiend](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Majesty%27s_Fiend), which simply says:

> Monster effects cannot be activated.

Given that [continuous monster effects are not impacted](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/47960/mystic-mine-vs-denko-sekka/47961#47961) by effects like that of Majesty's Fiend, we can clearly see a separation. In conclusion, **unless the card specifically says "cannot be activated,"** or some rearrangement thereof, **you can still attempt to activate the effect** - provided of course that you can pay activation cost.

Comment: In other words. You can activate it, but it will not resolve. Useful when you want to tribute a monster

Answer (score 0):

https://www.reddit.com/r/Yugioh101/comments/8pf1bg/how_tour_guide_helps_in_lair_of_darkness_deck/

From googling and reading that reddit post my conclusion is that you can activate the effect of lilith and sacrifice and enemy monster if you got lair of darkness but you can't reveal 3 normal traps etc because the effect is negated. So as I understand its not the activation thats activated only the effect. That means tributing a dark monster works but you don't gain anything from it. But I am ofter confused my yu gi oh effects so curious if someone else gives a better answer